# Angular 2 rxjs timeout callback

Tags: angular, timeout, rxjs

I want to provide feedback to the user if a timeout event on a HTTP call happens.

I tried this:

```
return this._http
                .post(apiUrl + 'Search/Everything', params, {withCredentials: true, headers: this.headers})
                .timeout(5000, this._feedbackService.error("Custom error message"))
                .map((response: Response) => response.json().data);
```

But that fires the feedback service as soon as the HTTP call is made.

How do I fire the service when the timeout kicks in?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming `_feedbackService.error` returns an `Error`, you should be able to do what you need with the [`timeoutWith`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-timeoutWith) and [`defer`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-defer) operators:

```
import "rxjs/add/observable‌​/defer";
import "rxjs/add/observable‌​/throw";
import "rxjs/add/operator/timeoutWith";
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable‌​";

return this._http
    .post(apiUrl + 'Search/Everything', params, {withCredentials: true, headers: this.headers})
    .timeoutWith(5000, Observable.defer(() => Observable.throw(this._feedbackService.error("Custom error message"))))
    .map((response: Response) => response.json().data);
```

Comment: Sorry. I answered this and then realised I'd misread the question. I've updated the answer.

Comment: What do I need to import besides `rxjs/add/operator/timeoutWith` to make this work? (the "Rx." part that is).

Comment: You will need `import "rxjs/add/observable/defer"` and `import "rxjs/add/observable/throw"`, too.

Comment: I still get a red squiggly line under "Rx.".

Comment: Sorry. Updated the code to use the minimal `Observable` together with the  appropriate `import` statements.

Comment: Thanks. But I get `Proterty 'defer' does not exist on type 'typeof Observable'` using that.

Comment: Sorry about that. An invisible space had made it's way before the last "/" in the path.

Comment: What's there now ought to be correct. Note that it's `rxjs/add/observable‌` - not `rxjs/add/operator` - for `defer` and `throw`. I'd answered a question earlier using the `import "rxjs/Rx"` and switching back and forth is a little tedious.