# Angular 6 rxjs timeout - timeout is not a function

Tags: angular6, rxjs6

I am trying to use timeout in one of my http post. I get error as

```
ERROR TypeError: this._http.post(...).timeout is not a function
```

This is how the code looks like:

```
return this._http.post(this.meetingProcessURL, body )
  .timeout(5000)
  .catch( err => { 
    return Observable.throw("Timeout has occurred");
  })

    .pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
  }
```

I am using angular 6 and rxjs 6.0.0

```
"@angular/core": "^6.1.0",
"rxjs": "^6.0.0",
"rxjs-compat": "^6.0.0",
```

What am I doing wrong?

ref: [Angular 2 rxjs timeout callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38990350/angular-2-rxjs-timeout-callback)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
return this._http.post(this.meetingProcessURL, body )
  .pipe(
    timeout(5000),
    catchError( err => { 
       return throwError("Timeout has occurred");
    })
  }
```

Since `rxjs@5.5` operators are not part of `Observable.prototype`, mainly for performance reasons. Read more [here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/pipeable-operators.md)

Comment: Great. Observable.throw was complaining but I was able to resolve using 
https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/3733

Comment: Observable.throw is now throwError()